# How to use "telemetry.cfg" and ".telemetry.cfg" files with Adobe Scout

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, adobe-scout

In the ***simplest language possible***, can someone please explain...

1. the function of the **"telemetry.cfg"** file when debugging an application with Adobe Scout?
2. the function of the **".telemetry.cfg"** file when debugging an application with Adobe Scout?
3. what `TelemetryAddress` is needed in each file

The only information I've found describing their functionality is very limited and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around these concepts.

---

*Some notes for reference...*

Example of "telemetry.cfg" file contents ("172.30.124.81" is the local IP of the machine running Scout):

```
TelemetryAddress = 172.30.124.81:7934
SamplerEnabled = false
CPUCapture = false
DisplayObjectCapture = false
Stage3DCapture = false
ScriptObjectAllocationTraces = false
```

And ".telemetry.cfg" could be the same except:

```
TelemetryAddress = localhost:7934
```

I've read this to be true:

> 7934 - Scout's default port
>   7935 - Flash Builder's default port

---

*Please don't just post a link to the official Adobe documentation; I've read it numerous times.*

Answer (score 1):

The `.telemetry.cfg` and `telemetry.cfg` file formats are the same.

Either one is **only** used when enabling Scout options to profile a `swf` in a remote process (i.e. on a different PC). This configuration file is *located on the PC that is running the `swf`* in order to tell the Flash runtime where to send its telemetry data and which data that it should send.

There is an iOS & Android app for configuring AIR on the actual mobile devices and thus the telemetry.cfg/.telemetry.cfg file is not used.

`telemetry.cfg` is used to config Air (via FlashBuilder) for profiling Blackberry 10s over their USB connection. Same options in the '.telemetry.cfg', just the IP is a link-local IPv4 address (169.254.x.x). Blackberry 10s are at end of life for support for AIR and I personally have not developed for them.

So in the Scout preferences:

[image]

- You can change the port number that Scout uses, and this port number has to match the one used in the `.telemetry.cfg` that is located on the remote PC.
- The "Make the Flash Runtime on thus computer connect to Scout" option actually creates a temporary ./telemetry.cfg that exists only while Scout run and is picked up by the Flash runtimes/SWFs that you run so profiling is automatic.

**TelemetryAddress** in the file is the IP (or host name) of the PC that is running Scout and the port address has to match the one assigned in the Scout Preferences (default is 7934)